# How to show ICollection as one String in GridController in c#, wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity, desktop-application

I have an object "User" which contains ICollection "Phone". I want to display them on TableView-GridController of DevExpress in one column as given below:

```
<dxg:GridColumn VisibleIndex="2"
        FieldName="User.Phone"
        IsSmart="True"
        ReadOnly="True"
        MinWidth="120"
        Header="Phone" />
```

I tried to make a new variable in my entity that carries all this Phone in one string as given below:

```
[NotMapped]
public string AllPhones
{
   get
   {
      string allPhones = "";
      if (Phone != null) 
      {
         foreach (var p in Phone)
         {
            allPhones += p.Lable + "\n";
         }
      }              
            return allPhones;
   }
}
```

Converted `FieldName="User.Phone"` to `FieldName="User.AllPhones"` But it's not working.

There is another way to solve this problem like to show Phones in DropDownList or show the first one.

Below is the data how I put in the GridController

```
var qry = SharedBll.Db.Patient.Take(100);
ContactGridControl.ItemsSource = qry.ToList();
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in the case of letters.
The binding is "User.allPhones" and the property is "AllPhones".

Comment: no it's the same

Comment: Can you see what is in the FieldName property: null or string.Empty?

Comment: virtual ICollection<Phone> Phone   is null but in the db there is  some Columns

Comment: So the problem is not in the code you showed.
Look for the reason why "ICollection <Phone> Phone" is not populating from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[NotMapped]
public string AllPhones
{
   get
   {
      string allPhones = "";
      foreach (var p in Phone)
      {
         allPhones += p.Lable + "\n";
      }            
      return allPhones;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly include the phones using [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data):

```
var qry = SharedBll.Db.Patient.Include(x => x.Phone).Take(100);
ContactGridControl.ItemsSource = qry.ToList();
```

Comment: now the problem of null disappears but they don't fetch the phones "i have 2 object contains phones in db"

Comment: Does the `Phone` property of any item in `qry.ToList()` return a non-empty collection then?

Comment: all of them is null idk what happened

Comment: Then it seems like you don't have any related entities. Maybe your mappings are incorrect.

Comment: how it's incorrect . i put public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phone { get; set; } in object of User do I forget any step ??